# Norton's equivalent circuit with independent sources

Tags: norton

I need to find the current flowing through \$R_{5}\$ by using Norton's theorem.

[image]

What I tried to do was:

1. Open-circuit the part of the circuit where there is \$R_{5}\$.
2. Calculate \$R_{n}\$ by open-circuiting the independent current sources (that is, \$I_{1}\$) and short-circuiting the voltage sources (\$V_{1}\$).
3. Calculate \$I_{n}\$ by short-circuiting the part where there is \$R_{5}\$.

So,

  2.

[image]

$$R_{n}=R_{4}+\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{2}+R_{3}}=7.5ohms$$

  3.

[image]

I used KCL to find \$V_{C}\$:

$$\frac{V_{1}-V_{C}}{R_{3}}+\frac{0-V_{C}}{R_{2}}+\frac{0-V_{C}}{R_{1}}-I_{1}=0$$

$$V_{C}=4.18V$$

Then,

$$I_{n}=\frac{V_{C}}{R_{4}}=\frac{4.18}{6}=0.696A$$

Apparently, \$I_{n}\$ is wrong, but I can't find any mistake in my reasoning. Any idea?

Comment: Try to write a proper KCL for Vc node. Because now your KCL is not consistent.

Comment: Current through R4 does not feature in your first node equation. Also some signs are wrong.

Comment: @G36 Okay, I checked my KCL, but I still get the wrong result.

Comment: What current direction you have assumed to be "positive" and what "negative"? Do you understand my question?

Comment: @G36 I'm assuming all the currents are coming into the node, and I always leave Vc at the end of the subtraction (v1-vc, 0-vc, etc.). That's what our professor told us. Is it okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm assuming all the currents are coming into the node, and I always
>   leave Vc at the end of the subtraction (v1-vc, 0-vc, etc.)

For sure you can do that. But notice that the \$I_1\$ current is leaving the \$V_C\$ node.

So the \$I_1\$ current needs to have a different sign.

I will show you two cases:

**First case:**

I will give a **minus sign** if the current entering the node (coming into the node).

And the **plus sign** if the current is leaving the node.

$$-\frac{V_1 - V_C}{R_3} - \frac{0 - V_C}{R_2} - \frac{0 - V_C}{R_4} + I_1 =0$$

Notice that I give \$I_1\$ the plus sign because \$I_1\$ is leaving the node (current source).

**Second case:**

Plus sign to all the currents that are entering the node.

$$\frac{V_1 - V_C}{R_3} + \frac{0 - V_C}{R_2} + \frac{0 - V_C}{R_4} - I_1 =0$$

Do you know why I give a minus sign to \$ I_1\$?

So what is important here is that you always must be consistent with the sign convention you have chosen when you are writing nodal equations.

And of course, those two "method" will give the same answer.

And we do not take \$R_1\$ resistor into account because \$R_1\$ is in series with the constant current source. Hence, it won't change the current in this branch.

Comment: But I include R4 in my KCL.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I have a question, though. The branch where R1 is, is it going to flow only I1 through it? Or it will flow I1 + the diverged current to that branch?

Comment: Only I1 current is flowing in the I1+R1 branch. In series circuit only one current can flow

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Everything makes sense now.